How do I commit to multiple repositories at the same time, with separate commit usernames based on each repository setting
Windows git https way how to achieve simultaneous push to multiple repositories, and according to each repository set a separate submission username
[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/jock/test
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    
[remote "gitlab"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/test
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*|

How do I set up the respective commit user names for github gitlab
github ：github-username

gitlab: gilab-username


What kind of submission username do you mean? Do your understand that user.name/user.email are not authorization credentials? They're commit identification data. They're used during commit creation and never used during pull/push. Logins/passwords, access tokens, SSH keypairs are authorization credentials. Are different logins what you name submission username? Or do you want to push commits with different user.name/user.email? The latter is impossible — you need to have two parallel branches with the same commit content but different identification data.

That is, I have a set of code stored on github and gitlab at the same time. I hope that when I submit the code, I can submit two repositories at once, and the username at the time of submission, github repository shows A gitlab repository shows B.

Nope, not possible without having different branches for different hostings. user.name/user.email identification are parts of commits.

if you need to change only the alias, try these steps. I tried different versions a few years ago, hope that works.

Set-Up Multiple Remotes (Possible, you have already these)

[remote "github"]
    url = https://github.com/jock/test
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
        
[remote "gitlab"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/test
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gitlab/*


Create a file in the ".git/hooks" directory of your repository

touch .git/hooks/pre-push
chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-push


a. Edit file like the following

#!/bin/sh

remote="$1"

if [ "$remote" = "github" ]; then
    git config user.name "github-username"
    git config user.email "github-email@example.com"
elif [ "$remote" = "gitlab" ]; then
    git config user.name "gitlab-username"
    git config user.email "gitlab-email@example.com"
fi


b. Push each remote

git push github
git push gitlab


Additionally, automate the pushing of all remotes in the git folder

    [alias]
        multipush = "!f() { git push github && git push gitlab; }; f"


Use it

    git multipush


I tried this method, but because you used two names, he pushed to two repository people at the same time, prompt need merge code

@laterday If the answer doesn't work for you — why did you accept it?
